# How to alter existing Atom.io Snippets

Tags: html, atom-editor, code-snippets

I'm looking to alter Atom.io preset HTML/CSS snippets, rather than creating new ones.
Specifially looking to change  tab

Ive tried using the .source in snippets.cson but had no luck

I want:
link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css"

to be: 
link rel="stylesheet" href=""

i have many other uses for this but this is one example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify your custom snippets in `snippets.cson`, you can overwrite the default snippets by using the same name as the [original snippet](https://github.com/atom/language-html/blob/v0.53.0/snippets/language-html.cson#L204-L206) (e.g. *"Link"*).

In the case of the link tag, that would be the following:

```coffee
'.text.html':
  'Link':
    'prefix': 'link'
    'body': '<link rel="${1:stylesheet}" href="$2">$0'
```

Comment: thank you so much! time saver for sure. ill have to learn where to add the $ symbols but this is a huge help!

Comment: Those tab-stops ($) are always placed in the order they will be accessed, except $0 which is reserved for the last tab-stop.

Comment: If the answer help, please mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will help others finding the answer quicker.